# feign.RetryableException: Connection refused: connect executing GET in docker

Tags: spring, docker-compose, spring-cloud

I have an solution using Spring boot 3 and Java 17. There are 3 apps, 1 of them communicate with other 2, The application is working in local environment, but when I put that on docker-compose I get the error feign.RetryableException: Connection refused: connect executing GET http://localhost:8082/v1/pois/search?name, I can access that url on broser, but not internally by an app using @FeignClient.

PoiFeignClient.class

```
@FeignClient(name = "poi-service")
public interface  PoiFeignClient {
    @GetMapping("/v1/pois/search")
    Page<PoiModal> search(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name, @PageableDefault(size = 10, sort = "name", direction = Sort.Direction.ASC) Pageable pageable);
}
```

applycation.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: vehicle-position-search-service
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher
  cache:
    type: redis
    redis:
      host: ${SPRING_REDIS_HOST}
      port: ${SPRING_REDIS_PORT}
      time-to-live: 60000
      cache-null-values: false
  datasource:
    url: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 20
      minimum-idle: 10
      idle-timeout: 10000
      pool-name: vehiclePositionSearchServicePoolConnection
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
server:
  port: 8080
  cloud:
    openfeign:
      client:
        config:
          poi-service:
            connect-timeout: 5000
            read-timeout: 5000
          vehicle-service:
            connect-timeout: 5000
            read-timeout: 5000
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  poi-service:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ../poi-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    depends_on:
      - eureka-server
      - postgres
      - redis
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/tb_veiculo
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: postgres
      SPRING_REDIS_HOST: redis
      SPRING_REDIS_PORT: 6379
    networks:
      - host
  vehicle-service:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ../vehicle-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/tb_veiculo
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: postgres
      SPRING_REDIS_HOST: redis
      SPRING_REDIS_PORT: 6379
    networks:
      - host
  vehicle-position-search-service:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ../vehicle-position-search-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
      - poi-service
      - vehicle-service
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/tb_veiculo
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: postgres
      SPRING_REDIS_HOST: redis
      SPRING_REDIS_PORT: 6379
    networks:
      - host
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: tb_veiculo
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    networks:
      - host
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - host
networks:
  host:
    driver: bridge
```